# Delete table row script deleting static AND appended rows instead of appended/current

Tags: javascript, html-table, append

I have a script working on a single page with a + button to append a row to the table and in the append row is included a - button to remove THAT row only. THREE rows are static and the plus button allows the user to add more rows if need be..

When I try running it on a separate page (I've changed the function name and button/table names) in a nested table - after clicking the + to append a new row (which works fine), soon as I click the "-" button it removes ALL the rows including the static ones, not just the current row.

I've tried closest in the function, it was parents before - neither work.. should I specify `table[1]` or something like that?

Here is the delete function:

```
$("body").on("click", "input.deleteRow", function() {
$("#RfqTable").closest("tr").remove();  
});
```

delete button:

```
input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="-" onclick = "deleteRow()"
```

table

```
table class="table table-bordered" id="RfqTable"
```

delete row button appended

```
input type="button" class="deleteRow" value="-" onclick = "deleteRow()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: In the JS function i changed this:

```
$("#RfqTable").closest("tr").remove();
```

to this

```
$("#RfqTable tr:last").remove();
```

and now its working -